# Saving Array to Realm in Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

Is it possible to save an array of objects to `Realm`? Anytime I make a change to the array it should be saved to Realm.

My current solution is to save object for object with a `for loop`. For append/modifying objects calling `save()` will do the job, but not when I remove an object from it.

```
class CustomObject: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var id = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
    }
}

struct RealmDatabase {

    static var sharedInstance = RealmDatabase()

    var realm: Realm!

    let object0 = CustomObject()
    let object1 = CustomObject()

    var array = [object0, object1]

    init() {
        self.realm = try! Realm()
    }

    func save() {

        for object in self.array {
            try! self.realm.write {
                self.realm.add(object, update: true)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the point of `RealmDatabase`? You can query the database directly using `realm.objects(CustomObject.self)`.

Answer (score 11):

To save lists of objects you have to use a Realm `List`, not a Swift Array.

```
let objects = List<CustomObject>()
```

Then, you can add elements:

```
objects.append(object1)
```

Take a look at [to many relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-many-relationships) and [Collections](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#collections) sections of [the official docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

```
func saveRealmArray(_ objects: [Object]) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(objects)
        }
    }
```

And then call the function passing an array of realm 'Object's:

```
saveRealmArray(myArray)
```

Note: realm.add(objects) has the same syntax of the add function for a single object, but if you check with the autocompletion you'll see that there is: add(objects: Sequence)

Comment: Are you sure that realm Objects do store order?