# Saving a Realm list made up of an array of struct objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift4

**Problem**
I need to save a List in Realm, which is made up of a the properties of an Array of Struct Objects (which has been passed through a Segue and is popualating a tableview).  This is in the form of an 'exercise name' and 'number of reps' on each row.

**What have I tried?**
I have matched the Realm Object with the Struct in terms of fields and format and attempted to save the array as a list e.g. "=List< array >" but this doesn't work ("use of undeclared type").  I've also tried various methods of trying to save the properties of each table row but again, couldn't get that to work (e.g. = cell.workoutname)

**Research** I found this [How to save a struct to realm in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060391/how-to-save-a-struct-to-realm-in-swift) however, this isn't for saving arrays of objects I don't think.  This **did** however (first answer), give me the idea of potentially saving the values contained within each row to Realm instead of the actual Struct array.  I also found this [Saving Array to Realm in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327569/saving-array-to-realm-in-swift)  but I think this is for when the array is already made up of Realm Objects, not Struct instances like in my case.

**Code and details**

**Structs**

I have a  Struct as per below.  Another struct, (Workout Generator) has a function which generates x number of instances of these objects.  These are then passed via a Segue to a new VC TableView (each row displays a workout name and number of reps):

```
struct WorkoutExercise : Hashable, Equatable{

    let name : String
    let reps : Int
    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.hashValue
    }

    static func == (lhs: WorkoutExercise, rhs: WorkoutExercise) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }


}
```

I then have the following Realm Objects.  One is for saving a 'WorkoutSession'.  This will contain a Realm List of WorkoutExercise Realm objects.

```
class WorkoutSessionObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var workoutID = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var workoutName = ""
    let exercises = List<WorkoutExerciseObject>()
    var totalExerciseCount: Int {
        return exercises.count
    }
}

class WorkoutExerciseObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
}
```

I have tried the following code when trying to save the Workout details to Realm :

```
func saveToRealm() {
        let workoutData = WorkoutSessionObject()
        workoutData.workoutName = "test"
        workoutData.workoutID = UUID().uuidString
        workoutData.exercises = List<selectedWorkoutExerciseArray>
    }
```

**What I *think* I need to do from reading the other answers**

**Option 1** - instead of trying to save the actual array, save the 'name' and 'reps' from each table row instead?

**Option 2** - somehow convert the 'selectedWorkoutExerciseArray' into a list of realm objects?

of course there might be other options!  Any help/ideas appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have both a `WorkoutExerciseObject` and the struct `WorkoutExercise` ?
If it makes sense to merge them, then you could manipulate an Array of `Object` directly.

Comment: It seems like a lot of work just to transform a struct to a realm object. Why not just uses classes? You won't need to create separate objects, etc.

Comment: When I change to a class, my function which generates a workout then gets an error of “name, reps,, does not match any available overloads” - is there something you need to change when using a class instead of a struct?

Comment: Well you already have a WorkoutExerciseObject that's a class, so not sure why you have the struct. I think you're making it too complicated for yourself. You can use Realm objects like any object in your code. There's no reason for similar objects to exist when you can just modify your realm objects to hold all the fields and methods you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why populate 2 separate lists if it needs to be persistent anyway? Just use the list in Realm to populate your table view. Here's a simple example of populating the list using append (just like any array):

```
class SomeClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    var someList = List<SomeOtherClass>()

    convenience init(id: String) {
        self.init()

        self.id = id
    }
}

@objcMembers class SomeOtherClass: Object {
    dynamic var someValue: String = ""

    convenience init(value: String) {
        self.init()

        someValue = value
    }
}

func addToList(someOtherClass: SomeOtherClass) {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    if let someClass = realm.objects(SomeClass.self).last {

        do {
            try realm.write({
                someClass.someList.append(someOtherClass)
            })
        } catch {
            print("something went wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now using a Class in my function instead of a struct (and have deleted the struct) and this works fine thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar functionality, that allow the user to select from a table view. What I do is create a List from the selection like:

```
var arrayForSelectedObjects = [CustomObject]()
...

let aList = List<CustomObject>()
aList.append(objectsIn: arrayForSelectedObjects)

//I then assign the created list to the main object and save it.
let realmObject = MainObject()
realmObject.list = aList
```

My CustomObject is also stored on the realm db.

My MainObject is defined like so:

```
class MainObject : Object {
    @objc dynamic var title: String?

    var list = List<CustomObject>()
}
```

Comment: I get 'use of undeclared type' when I try this - I think it might be because I am using a struct whereas are you using 2 realm object classes?

Comment: @nc14 I am using classes, but if I understand correctly you are also saving classes `class WorkoutSessionObject: Object` and `class WorkoutExerciseObject: Object`. How do you create the exercises list?