# How do u save Array of object to Realm, Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I'm new to Swift Realm. Here's my method to save single object.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

    func savePerson(_ person: Person){
        do{
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(person)
            }
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Is there any method to save Array?

```
func savePersonList(_ personList: []){
    do{
        try realm.write{
            // HOW??
        }
    }catch{

    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `add`. It accepts a `Sequence` too.

Comment: Seriously? I didn't know that.

Comment: Yep. Go ahead and try it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327569/saving-array-to-realm-in-swift

Comment: Do you have a class which will become a table in Realm?

Comment: Realm doesn't have arrays as Realm objects. You should take a look at the [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) as it's what you should use instead, depending on the use case. Can you clarify what you are actually doing? In other words, you can append an array of objects inside a write like this `jim.dogs.append(objectsIn: dogArray)`. While dog Array is an Array, you can do that with any kind of sequence like results, lists or arrays. However, it's not appending the actual array, it's iterating over the items *in* the array and adding them to the existing list.